# How do I add menu-entry to the admin menu with node reference?

Tags: 7

Task:
I want to add an `edit` option in the admin menu that would only appear while viewing a node while logged in as admin.
The link of the edit item can be like `node\%\edit` so that clicking on the link would take the user to its edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Menu Token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module to achieve the same:

1. Install the module and its dependency, i.e. the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module.
2. Create a new menu item with path `node/[node:nid]/edit`.
3. Place the menu block which contains the menu item in any region of your choice.
4. Drupal menu system takes care of showing the menus as per the access; which means that only users which have permission to edit the node should see it.

The image below is an example shown on the project page. You could use it as a guide.

[image: Menu token PDF]